# send data with ajax jquery method

Tags: jquery, ajax

I really appreciate your helps, please help me one more thing, i have the following code, can you pleae tell me where am i doing it wrong?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<script>

function upd(str)
{
$.ajax({
       type:'post',
       url:'upld.php',
       datatype:'html',
       data:'fname='+str,
       success:function(response)
       {
            $("#ee").load("upld.php");  
       }
       });
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<select name="nmae" id="nmae" onChange="upd(this.value)">
<option value="dd">dd</option>
<option value="cc">cc</option>
</select>
<div id="ee"></div>
```

and my upld.php file consists of :

```
<?php

$k= $_POST["game"];
echo $k;


?>
```

Comment: this is wrong: ``data:'fname='+str``

Comment: do :``data:{'fname':str``}

Comment: dude but it still dosn't work!

Comment: @user3682527 check you console what error you get when you select

Comment: @EhsanSajjad he is using html type, not json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you try to do is this:

```
function upd(str){
    $.ajax({
       type:'post',
       url:'upld.php',
       datatype:'text',
       data:{'fname': str},
       success:function(response)
       {
           $("#ee").text(response);  
       }
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot dude it worked finally, only because of "$("#ee").text(response); "

Answer (score 1):

In your PHP you looking for a POST variable 'game', the only POST variable you are sending though is 'fname'

```
data:'fname='+str,

$k= $_POST["game"];
```

switch the variables to match, or add the additional variable you are looking for

Comment: Yeah that was a dumm mistake it should be $k= $_POST["fname"] but it still did't worked for me

Answer (score 1):

There are two changes to be done in your ajax method:

```
   datatype:'text', // as you  are echoing text only so change it to "text"
   data:{'fname':str}, // send object this way
```